# Any Object-Oriented Flexible Java x86 Disassembler Library?

Tags: java, x86, visitor-pattern, disassembly

I am looking for a Java x86 disassembler library that should have following features:

- Disassembling X86 Code
- Describing X86 commands with Java classes and Objects
- The command classes should accept a visitor which has a generic return value

So, if I have some code that would disassemble like this:

```
MOV EAX, EBX
CALL 1234
JMP 88
```

then the library should create three objects for MOV, CALL and JMP. Then I implement a visitor that does diverse things (ex: interpreting, converting to x64 or to an instruction for another processor architecture).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe that exists such a disassembler, because assembler is procedural. So you can't convert from procedural into Object Oriented without redesign the application and that must be done by hand.

Comment: The point is not about converting procedural to object-oriented design. I just want a library that describes the procedures as Java objects and I can do whatever I want with them.

Comment: But why don't you use a regular x86 disassembler to disassemble the binary and parse the output with a Java-Programm. You can then simply read the disassembled code in a list of objects that represents MOV or CALL instructions; or you could try to build a tree structure trying to identify subelements by jump instructions.

Comment: this would prevent one doing interactive things such as interpretation. Otherwise, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not quite. But there are `Java` bindings for e.g. [`Capstone`](https://www.capstone-engine.org/).

Here are [`maven` bindings](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.transcurity/capstone). [Here](http://www.capstone-engine.org/download.html) you can download the native libraries. [Here](https://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_java.html) is a Java code example.

```
// Test.java
import capstone.Capstone;

public class Test {

  public static byte [] CODE = { 0x55, 0x48, (byte) 0x8b, 0x05, (byte) 0xb8,
    0x13, 0x00, 0x00 };

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    Capstone cs = new Capstone(Capstone.CS_ARCH_X86, Capstone.CS_MODE_64);
    Capstone.CsInsn[] allInsn = cs.disasm(CODE, 0x1000);
    for (int i=0; i<allInsn.length; i++)
      System.out.printf("0x%x:\t%s\t%s\n", allInsn[i].address,
          allInsn[i].mnemonic, allInsn[i].opStr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any such library implemented entirely Java. Although, I do heard about [distorm](http://code.google.com/p/distorm/) disassembler. It is developed in C. But Java wrappers are available for this library. Have a look at it. It may be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for hinting on distorm. But I see it has two disadvantages: first, it is not really object oriented and the decoded instructions don't accept a visitor. second, it contains the operands as a string, which means they must be re-parsed.

Comment: Writing a visitor abstraction for something that provides you with detailed support should be easy. The really hard part is the "parsing the machine code", and distorm seems to be good at that. Also, this does not look like string-parsing to me: http://code.google.com/p/distorm/source/browse/trunk/examples/java/distorm/src/diStorm3/Operand.java